# A math prime symbol instead of single quote in text mode

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I have an abbreviated name say ABC and I want to write something like ABC', but I prefer the quote to be the math mode prime symbol. Something like `ABC$'$` will give me that, but is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: You could define `\DeclareRobustCommand{\textprime}{$'$}`

Comment: There is also $\textrm{ABC}^\prime$ but it looks identical.